# Memory Leaks in Java (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks

My custom JPanel is retaining a large number of int arrays, as seen below in YourKit:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/a1437a032186afdbd64a1dac1c6e64fb.png))</sub>

I assumed this was the result of Graphic objects being undisposed of, but even with disposing every graphics object I use, the memory issues still occur.

The garbage collector will remove the objects if I force a heap dump (and the arrays are marked as unreachable). The behaviour causes Java to reach a high memory allocation (~700MB) however.

Are there any other common sources of this sort of issue in swing/JPanels?

Comment: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19468.html

Comment: This isn't the result of listeners though - it occurs with the frequent rendering to a single JPanel, not changing JPanels or anything.

Comment: The display says "unreachable". What makes you think they're "retained"?

Comment: Well, retained perhaps is the wrong word. I mean the GC is not removing them with any particular speed, which causes the heap size to skyrocket.

Comment: Unless you see `OutOfMemoryError` it is likely just that the Garbage Collector is being conservative.  Don't obsess about memory profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a custom `JPanel`, consider using `JTable`, which uses the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to [render](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) only visible cells. Moreover, a suitable [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) may allow you to minimize the memory required for data storage. Finally, `JTable` supports [sorting and filteri](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)ng in a way that may make large datasets more manageable by the user.